# cron jobs made in cPanel don't show up in PuTTy

Tags: command-line, putty, cron, crontab

Why don't cron jobs, that I have made in cPanel, show up when I use PuTTy and type `crontab -l`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each user on a system has the potential to schedule `cron` jobs. In other words, there can be many separate sets of cron jobs.

Try `ls /var/spool/cron` to see a list of users with scheduled jobs.

If the job you scheduled was a script named foo, try `grep -l foo /var/spool/cron/*` to find out which user scheduled it.

The `crontab` command has a `-u` option to specifiy the user. You can use this to view the jobs created in cPanel.

You most likely need to be logged on as root or use `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing the user of whm or host is `ashkany`, try:

```
cd /var/spool/cron
dir
```

See user --> my user is ashkany:

```
nano ashkany
```

Change something and save it.

Same:
(run just in 1:23 min every night)

```
1 23 * * * /usr/local/bin/php/ -p /home/ashkany/public_html/cron.php
```

(run every 30 min)

```
*/30 * * * /usr/local/bin/php/ -p /home/ashkany/public_html/30.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Have no idea why they are not visible there.
Under putty just add them by:

```
crontab -e
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I can think of would be to check the user for whom the cron was created for.  You won't see the crontab if you aren't logged in as the same user the crontab was created for in cpanel.

I have never used cpanel, so I don't know if there's an option to create crons for different user or whatnot, so forgive me if I'm off base with this one.

Good luck!

Comment: I guess your right about it being a user issue. because if i add the jobs through cpanel they work but if i add the exact same line of code via putty it doesn't work.